# Simplifying a sum to calculate its limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, summation

I am currently learning about limits and have hit a small roadblock.

Given

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{n(n+2)}$$

I want to calculate the limit on my own (which results in $\frac{3}{4}$). The book in which this is explained (and solved) calculates the limit correctly and step by step. What it does not show is how to simplify the sum from the above to the following:

$$\frac{n(3n+5)}{4(n+1)(n+2)}$$

I appreciate any help!

Comment: I do not immediately see where $\frac {n(3n+5)}{4(n+1)(n+2)}$ comes from.  But if you divide numerator and denominator by $n^2$ you will get $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \frac {3+\frac {5}{n}}{4(1+\frac {1}{n})(1+\frac {2}{n})}$  and as $n$ gets large you are left with $\frac 34$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{n(n+2)}=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \left(\frac{1}{n}- \frac{1}{n+2}\right)=\frac12\left(1\color{red}{-\frac13}+\frac12\color{red}{-\frac14+\frac13-\frac15+\frac14-\frac16+...}\right)$$

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick help! Is there a name for the method you used to calculate this or did you come up with this by yourself because it is so trivial?

Comment: It is a partial fraction deomposition, refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition

Comment: @user1994928 in this case we are looking for $$\frac{1}{n(n+2)}=\frac{a}{n}+\frac{b}{n+2}=\frac{an+2a+bn}{n(n+2)}\implies a=-b \quad a=\frac12$$

Comment: Thanks, now partial fraction decomposition makes sense. Now if I can make sense out of the sum, they all cancel out due to the n and n+2 parts, which then only leaves $1+\frac{1}{2}$, no matter how big the sum gets. This turns into $\frac{3}{2}$ which leaves $\frac{1}{2} * \frac{3}{2}$ which is the $\frac{3}{4}$ I'm looking for, right?

Comment: @user1994928 Yes exactly! Well done

Comment: Strictly speaking, these manipulations, especially the final rearrangement of terms to cancel them pairwise, need to be justified, but no one bothers to do that, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $${1\over n(n+2)} = {1\over 2}{2\over n(n+2)}  = {1\over 2}{(n+2)-n\over n(n+2)}  = {1\over 2}({1\over n} -{1\over n+2}) $$